# Prove bijection

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose $m$ is a positive integer relatively
prime to |G|. Prove that the map $f : G → G$ given by $f(x) = x^
m$ is a
bijection (hint: prove f is one-to-one and use the fact that $x^
{|G|} = e)$.

I thought about $f(a) = f(b)$ then $a^m = b^m$ but then $a$ can be $\pm b$ or am I wrong?
I know that I have to prove that it is injective and surjective.
That $f(a) = f(b) => a = b$ and $f(x) = y $

Comment: Note that if you write $G$ multiplicatively (and otherwise the map $f$ would make no sense) then there is no such thing as $-b$. Also note that you only have to show one, injectivity or surjectivity (why?).

Comment: Because the number of elements are the same. If it is injective then it is surjective in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(m,|G|)=1$ there are integers $x,y$ such that 
$$xm+y|G|=1.$$
Now assume that $a^m=b^m$ and obviously $a^{|G|}=b ^{|G|}$, then
$$a^{xm+y|G|}=b^{xm+y|G|}\Longrightarrow a=b.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: This is not what I said, we chose $x,y$ such that $xm+y|G|=1$.